# remove spaces and gaps between div containers

Tags: html, css, materialize

How can i remove the spaces between div containers (on the bottom part div that has a border of red)? below is my snippets and I use materializecss

```css
/*############################ LOGIN STYLE ############################*/
body{
    font: normal 15px "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #ebebeb;
}
a{text-decoration: none;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5{font-family: 'mpsemibold', sans-serif;}
a, .transation{
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.extend{max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;}
.clear{clear: both; float: none;}
.center{margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
.thehide{display: none;}
.align_left{float: left;}
.align_right{float: right;}
.display_table{display: table;}
.inline{display: inline-block;}
.bgwhite{background: #fff;}
/* ###################### start ###################### */
/* header */
#topheader{
    background: #7d7d7d;
    padding: 15px;
}
.logo_wrapper, .menu_wrapper{
    width: 80%;
}
.logo{
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* navigation */
#topnav{
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  
}
#topnav li{
    float: left;
}
#topnav li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    color: #e5e5e5;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#topnav li a span{
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
#topnav li a span:first-child{
    margin-right: 3px;
}
#topnav li a span:last-child{
    padding-top: 2px;
}
#topnav li a.active_menu, #topnav li a:active, #topnav li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}
#mobile_nav{
top: 80px;
left: 20px;
position: fixed;
z-index:99999;
}
/* dropdown */
#topnav .dropdown_menu{
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    background: #263238;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    
}
#topnav .dropdown_menu li{
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
#topnav .dropdown_menu a{
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.side-nav li a{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
/* dropdown */
#topnav .dropdown_menu{
    
}
#topnav .dropdown_menu li{
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
#topnav .dropdown_menu a{
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    
}
/* right option */
.right_option_wrapper ul{padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
.right_option_wrapper ul li{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}
.right_option_wrapper ul:first-child{
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.right_option_wrapper ul li a{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 25px;
}
#idty a{
    font: normal 15px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 7px;
    display: block;
}
#idty a span{
    float: left;
}
#idty a span:first-child{
    margin-right: 3px;
}
.right_option_wrapper img{
-webkit-border-radius: 5000px;
-moz-border-radius: 5000px;
border-radius: 5000px;
}
/* boxes */
#boxes{
    padding: 7px;
}
.box{
    background: #76b729;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 23%;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    height: 90px;
}
.box_content_container{
    padding-top: 7px;
}
.box .icon{
    font-size: 4em;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.box h1, h2{text-transform: uppercase; text-align: left; color: #fff; clear: both;}
.box h1{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
    font: 400 30px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.box h1 span{
    float: left;
    font: 400 30px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    display: block;
}
.box h1 span:last-child{
    color: rgba(255,255,25,0.5);
    font: 300 15px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.box h2{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font: 400 10px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
/* announcement and workflow */
#second_container .s6{
    width: 49.5%;
    padding: 7px;
}
#second_container .col:first-child{
    margin-right: 5px !important;
}
.title_header{
    font: 500 18px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    color: #263238;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #76b729;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    color: #76b729;
}
.title_header span{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
}
.title_header span:first-child{
    margin-right: 7px;
}
.content{
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.content_content{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    
}
.content_content h1{
    font: 500 15px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #6c6c6c;
    padding: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}
.content_content h1 span{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.content_content h1 span:first-child{
    margin-right: 3px;
}
.content_content p{
    font: 300 13px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #6c6c6c;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <!-- materialize -->
        <script src="http://megamitch.ph/materializecss/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <link href="http://megamitch.ph/materializecss/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        
        <!-- webfont -->
        <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainwrapper" class="row extend clear center">
            <div class="col s12 extend clear" id="topheader">
                <div class="clear extend">
                    <a id="mobile_nav" data-activates="mobile-demo" style="visibility: hidden;" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light green"><i class="mdi-content-add"></i></a>
                    <a href="index.html" class="left logo extend clear" title="MOT HRIS">Test</a>
                    <div class="right display_table right_option_wrapper">
                        <ul class="left extend">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-help-outline"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-list-outline"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-information-outline"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="left extend ">
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="core/img/avatar.png" width="30" height="30"/></a></li>
                            <li id="idty">
                                <a href="#"><span>Corp</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="extend clear nav-wrapper">
                    <ul class="nav extend clear" id="topnav">
                        <li><a href="index.html" title="home" class="active_menu">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="Company" class="xx"><span>Company</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="HR" class="xx"><span>HR</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" title="#">Assets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" title="#">Employees</a></li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="Expenses" class="xx"><span>expenses</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="HR" class="xx"><span>PERFORMANCE</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="Recruitment" class="xx"><span>recruitment</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" title="#">reporting</a></li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="self service" class="xx"><span>self service</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" title="#">timesheets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" title="#">Timeoff</a></li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="training" class="xx"><span>training</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="more" class="xx"><span>more</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                       <li><a href="index.html" title="home" class="active_menu">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="Company" class="xx"><span>Company</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="HR" class="xx"><span>HR</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" title="#">Assets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" title="#">Employees</a></li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="Expenses" class="xx"><span>expenses</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="HR" class="xx"><span>PERFORMANCE</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="Recruitment" class="xx"><span>recruitment</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" title="#">reporting</a></li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="self service" class="xx"><span>self service</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" title="#">timesheets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" title="#">Timeoff</a></li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="training" class="xx"><span>training</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has_dp">
                            <a href="#" title="more" class="xx"><span>more</span><span class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown_menu extend clear thehide">
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dropdown menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="clear extend" style="height: 15px;"></div>
            <div class="col s6" id="left_container">
                <div class="row clear bgwhite center" id="boxes">
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-ios-people left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1>17</h1>
                            <h2>Employees</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-calendar left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1><span>1</span><span>5.9%</span></h1>
                            <h2>Time off today</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-android-calendar left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1>0%</h1>
                            <h2>ABSENCE RATE</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-calendar left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1><span>0</span><span>0%</span></h1>
                            <h2>UNAUTHORIZED TODAY</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-pie-graph left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1>65,369</h1>
                            <h2>TOTAL BENEFITS</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-stats-bars left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1>468,739</h1>
                            <h2>TOTAL SALARY</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-arrow-graph-up-right left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1>534,108</h1>
                            <h2>total cost</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-arrow-graph-up-right left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1>31,418</h1>
                            <h2>average cost</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-share left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1><span>0</span><span>0%</span></h1>
                            <h2>starters</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-share left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1><span>0</span><span>0%</span></h1>
                            <h2>leavers</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-android-list left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1><span>0</span><span>0%</span></h1>
                            <h2>training today</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-alert-circled left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1><span>0</span><span>0%</span></h1>
                            <h2>warnings</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-arrow-up-a left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1><span>0</span><span>0%</span></h1>
                            <h2>high performers</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-arrow-down-a left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1><span>0</span><span>0%</span></h1>
                            <h2>low performers</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-person-stalker left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1>0</h1>
                            <h2>users</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-document-text left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1>9</h1>
                            <h2>documents</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-ios-list left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1>2</h1>
                            <h2>open requisitions</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extend inline_block left box">
                        <span class="icon ion-person left extend"></span>
                        <div class="box_content_container extend left">
                            <h1>2</h1>
                            <h2>candidates</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               
                <div class="row extend center" id="second_container">
                    <div class="col s6 bgwhite" id="announcement">
                        <h1 class="title_header extend clear"><span class="ion-speakerphone"></span><span>Announcement</span></h1>
                        <div class="row content extend clear">
                            <div class="content_content extend clear">
                               <h1><span>Sample badge</span><span>Sample Title</span></h1>
                                <p>This is the sample content of this post</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s6 bgwhite" id="workflow">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s6" id="right_container">
                sdasd
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer: elements set to be `display: inline-block` end up with spacing between them. An easy fix is to have the first closing tag end on the same line as the next open tag:

```
<div>
...
</div><div>
...
</div>
```